# ArrayMinumun () returning last value

Tags: arrays, mql4, expert-system

i'm trying to find the lowest value in an array that is determined between the last closed order and Timecurrent().
I'm always getting the last value of the buffer instead the minimum value of the array.
I've tried to change every parameter but so far no luck.
Please could you help me out?

```
int ArrayCalcMin()
   {   
      datetime Timeorder=LastOrderTime();
      datetime Timeahora=TimeCurrent();
      datetime Times=Timeahora-Timeorder;
      
                
      int m = TimeMinute(Times);
      int h = TimeHour(Times);
      int d = TimeDay(Times);
      int bars = (((d-1)*24*60)+(h*60)+m)/240;
      int malookback=bars;
     
        
            
      double madaily[30000];
      double dllv;
      
      for(int i = 1; i < malookback; i++)
                  
      {
      
      madaily[i] = iCustom(NULL,0,"Scolor8",0,i);
         
      
      dllv = iCustom(NULL,0,"Scolor8",0,
             ArrayMinimum(madaily,WHOLE_ARRAY,0));
     }
     Print("Minimum value : ",dllv);
      
      if (dllv < 50){return(1);malookback=0; }
      else {return(0);malookback=0;}
      
   }
```

Thank you in advance.
KR
Andrés

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing how to use `ArrayMinimum()` and you are definitely over complicating finding the bars to look at. Try the following code

```
int ArrayCalcMin()
{
   double madaily[1], dllv;
   ArrayResize(madaily, iBarShift(NULL, 0, LastOrderTime()));

   for(int i=0; i<iBarShift(NULL, 0, LastOrderTime()); i++) madaily[i]=iCustom(NULL, 0, "Scolor8", 0, i);
   dllv = madaily[ArrayMinimum(madaily, WHOLE_ARRAY, 0)];

   Print("Minimum value : ",dllv);

   if(dllv<50) return(1);
   else return(0);
}
```